# Eloquent with eager loading returning null valued array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I am using laravel 5.2 and when executing the following, I am being returned by a null value for answers.

```
$id = Request::input('id');

    $question = Question::where('q_id','=',$id)->with(
        array('answers'=>function($query){
            $query->select('answer','aid');
        })
    )
    ->get();
    return $question;
```

Question model:

```
class Question extends Model
{
protected $table="questions";
protected $primaryKey = 'q_id';

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comments','qid','q_id');
}

public function qtags()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Question_tags','q_id','q_id');
}

public function answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Answers','qid','q_id');
}

}
```

Question_tags:

```
class Question_tags extends Model
{
protected $table="question_tags";

public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tags','tag_id','tagid');
}
}
```

Database:

```
COMMENTS table
-qid
-comment

Question table:
-qid
-title
-body

Answers table:
-aid
-qid
-answer
```

I have used the eager loading previously but never got this wierd error. I found some similar questions in the stackoverflow where the problem being in the relationships. Did I mess up the relationships.

Comment: Dont be lazy name your keys properly and you wont have problems.

Comment: will remember @Kyslik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't load comments. You need to add this relationship to `with()`:

```
$question = Question::where('q_id','=',$id)->with([
    'comments',
    'answers' => function($q) {
        $q->select('answer','aid');
    }])
    ->get();
```

**Update**

In comments you said you're having problems with `answers`, but not `comments`. In this case try to add key to `select()`:

```
$query->select('answer','aid', 'qid');
```

Comment: sorry, it was null for answers.modified it

Comment: @uttejh because with `select()` you've cutted out foreign key, so no relation could be found.